# How to reorder bars in the chart and the legend

Tags: r

I'm struggling to reorder the bars in the plot and the legend, following the data structure (SD,MB,FI,FO,NP).
Here is my data;

```
    Data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year,    ~SD,    ~MB,      ~FI,       ~FO,       ~NP,
  "2010",   41,     36.7,    10.2,        5.3,     6.8,
  "2011",   49.1,   50.9,    NA,          NA,      NA,
  "2012",   41.1,   32.4,    11.4,        8.6,     6.4,
  "2013",   38.9,   29.6,    10,          13.7,    7.7,
  "2014",   38.8,   36.5,    5.2,         10.4,    9,
  "2015",   43.4,   39.1,    NA,          11.9,    5.5, 
  "2016",   40.6,   38,      10.5,        8.8,     2.2,
  "2017",   38.3,   42.3,    9.7,         6.8,     2.9,
  "2018",   37.8,   40.3,    9.3,         10.6,    2,
  "2019",   33.8,   41.6,    8.1,         14.2,    2.3
```

)

The code;

```
    Data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = name, reorder(TRUE))) +  ylab("Students") +
  xlab("Year") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ Year, scales = 'free_x', ncol = 10, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
         axis.text.x=element_blank(),
         axis.ticks.x=element_blank()+
   theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
         panel.spacing    = unit(0, "points"),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.background.y = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(), 
        strip.text       = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9)) +
   scale_fill_continuous(name = "Legend", label = c("SD","MB","FI","FO","NP", ordered(TRUE))) + 
   theme(legend.position = "right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.4)))
```

thank you in advance.

**Here is the edit on the code:**

The csv file is here: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjskoWp__th-kEJOld80Tb0Bxx-C?e=JoSmGf

```
Rtutorial <- read.csv("C:Desktop/statistics/Rtutorial.csv", header=TRUE)

Rtutorial<-as.data.frame(Rtutorial)

library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

Rtutorial %>%

  pivot_longer(c(-Year, -Total))) %>%

  mutate(name = factor(name, levels=c('Total',
                                      'Sable-Antelope',
                                      'Monkey',
                                      'Frogs and reed buck',
                                      'Fox and jackals',
                                      'Side striped jackal'
                                    ))) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Year), y=value, fill=name, reorder(TRUE))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format()) +
  ylab("Total Population") +
  xlab("Year") +
  labs(fill="Legend") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank() ,
    legend.position = "right", 
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 0)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens", name = "Legend", label=c('Total 
Population','Sable-Antelope','Monkey','Frogs and reed buck','Fox and 
jackals','Side striped jackal', ordered(T)) + 
theme(legend.position = "right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 
90,vjust = 0.4)))
```

I still get errors when I run the code, I tried looking at several examples on stackoverflow and couldn't see where the problem is.

One of the errors I get is with Error in factor - name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put this line:

```
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels=c("SD","MB","FI","FO","NP"))) %>%
```

after your `pivot_longer(-Year)` function, it should work.  This will make the variable `name` into a factor with the levels ordered as you want.

```
Data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels=c("SD","MB","FI","FO","NP"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = name, reorder(TRUE))) +  ylab("Students") +
  xlab("Year") +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ Year, scales = 'free_x', ncol = 10, strip.position = "bottom") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank()+
          theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
                panel.spacing    = unit(0, "points"),
                axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
                strip.background = element_blank(),
                strip.background.y = element_blank(),
                panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
                panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
                panel.border = element_blank(), 
                strip.text       = element_text(face = "bold", size = 9)) +
          scale_fill_continuous(name = "Legend", label = c("SD","MB","FI","FO","NP", ordered(TRUE))) + 
          theme(legend.position = "right", axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.4)))
```

[image]

---

**EDIT** - answer comment below.

You could streamline the function a bit, like the following:

````
Data <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Year,    ~`Sable-Antelope`,    ~`Monkey`,      ~`Frogs and reed buck`,       ~`Fox and jackals`,       ~`Side striped jackal`,
  "2010",   41,     36.7,    10.2,        5.3,     6.8,
  "2011",   49.1,   50.9,    NA,          NA,      NA,
  "2012",   41.1,   32.4,    11.4,        8.6,     6.4,
  "2013",   38.9,   29.6,    10,          13.7,    7.7,
  "2014",   38.8,   36.5,    5.2,         10.4,    9,
  "2015",   43.4,   39.1,    NA,          11.9,    5.5, 
  "2016",   40.6,   38,      10.5,        8.8,     2.2,
  "2017",   38.3,   42.3,    9.7,         6.8,     2.9,
  "2018",   37.8,   40.3,    9.3,         10.6,    2,
  "2019",   33.8,   41.6,    8.1,         14.2,    2.3)


Data %>%
  pivot_longer(-Year) %>% 
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels=c("Sable-Antelope",
                                      "Monkey",
                                      "Frogs and reed buck",
                                      "Fox and jackals",
                                      "Side striped jackal"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = value, fill = name)) +  
  ylab("Students") +
  xlab("Year") +
  labs(fill="Legend") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens") +  
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank() ,
    legend.position = "right", 
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = 7.5))```
````

[image]

---

**EDIT 2** - Using updated data and syntax.

There were a couple of things that prevented your code from running.

1. It looks like you want the `Total` group in the plot as well, so you shouldn't select it out in the `pivot_longer()` function.
2. There was an extra parenthesis at the end of the `pivot_longer()`
3. When you use `read.csv()` spaces in variable names are replaces with periods, so the levels you're specifying won't work.  You'll have to specify the levels as the names with periods and the labels as the names with spaces instead of periods.
4. While less problematic, the second `theme()` call overrides things in the first `theme()` call.  These could be combined.

The code below solves these problems.

```
Rtutorial %>%
  
  pivot_longer(c(-Year)) %>%
  
  mutate(name = factor(name, levels=c('Total',
                                       'Sable.Antelope',
                                       'Monkey',
                                       'Frogs.and.reed.buck',
                                       'Fox.and.jackals',
                                       'Side.striped.jackal'), 
                             labels=c('Total',
                                      'Sable-Antelope',
                                      'Monkey',
                                      'Frogs and reed buck',
                                      'Fox and jackals',
                                      'Side striped jackal'))) %>%
  
  ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Year), y=value, fill=name, reorder(TRUE))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma_format()) +
  ylab("Total Population") +
  xlab("Year") +
  labs(fill="Legend") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(strip.placement  = "outside",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank() ,
        legend.position = "right", 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90,vjust = 0.4)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens", name = "Legend")
```

[image]

Comment: That helps, Thanks @DaveArmstrong. but how do I change the color to a pallet of green shades and the legend to be labelled as legend not name?

Comment: It works well, but I get errors when I change the column headings to my data which are names.

Comment: I want to change the column headings from ~SD,    ~MB,      ~FI,       ~FO,       ~NP to ~Sable-Antelope,    ~Monkey,      ~Frogs and reed buck,       ~Fox and jackals,       ~Side striped jackal

Comment: @MisBlearnsR - edited again to use the variable names you want. The trick is with names that include spaces or other special characters, you need to enclose them in back ticks - `\``.

Comment: But I'm struggling to get the right plot when I run my imported data which is saved in csv format.

Comment: https://1drv.ms/x/s!AjskoWp__th-kECz34PmTiKmGP3c?e=niPKbD

Comment: @MisBlearnsR there were just a couple of small problems.  One is that there is a `Total` column in your data, so the `pivot_longer()` call should be `pivot_longer(c(-Year, -Total))` and when you specify `ggplot()`, you should do `ggplot(aes(x=as.factor(Year), y=value, fille=name))`.  Everything else should work.

Comment: I still get an error. I included an edit of the code and the data below the question.

Comment: @MisBlearnsR I just added another edit to the answer to solve the problems.